# Konditionalsätze mit "wüsste"

Tags: grammatical-case

Als ich den Text der Geschichte (Klabund. "Der sterbende Soldat") analysierte, fand ich einen Satz, dessen Bedeutung mir nicht ganz klar ist:

***Wenn der Wachtmeister wüßte, daß ich hier so faul liege, während er Appell hält***. *"Ulan Bubenreuther", wird er rufen. "Ulan Bubenreuther ...?" Niemand meldet sich. "Ulan Bubenreuther vermißt ...".*

Wie ist der erste Satz zu verstehen? Ich habe zwei Möglichkeiten:

(i) Wenn der Wachtmeister gewusst hätte, dass ich während des Appells hier liege (= Wenn der Wachtmeister herausgefunden hätte, dass ich nicht am Appell teilnehme, hätte es ihm nicht gefallen).

(ii) Hätte gewusst, dass ich hier beim Zählappell liege (= Wachmeister nimmt den Zählappell vor, weiß aber nicht, dass ich hier liege. Es wäre schön, wenn er davon wüsste).

Comment: Wie der Wachtmeister das findet, ist nicht festgelegt. Wodurch denn auch?

Answer (score 2):

(i) ist korrekt. Theoretisch könnte man "wenn ... wüsste, dass ..." auch in einem positiven Fall (ii) verwenden, aber übrlicherweise bedeutet es, dass es gut ist, dass Person xyz die Tatsache nicht weiß

Comment: Ich verstehe leider nicht ganz, wie du zu der Aussage kommst. Das hat mit "positiv" oder "negativ" überhaupt nichts zu tun. Vielleicht wär's ja auch im Fall (i) ganz positiv, wenn der Wachtmeister wüsste, dass der Soldat da liegt, und ihm einen Sanitäter schicken würde.

Answer (score 2):

Die Bedeutung der Sätze ist ja in dieser Geschichte immer etwas neblig, weil es sich um eine Art Fiebertraum-Sequenz handelt.

Was man zu dem Satz

> Wenn der Wachtmeister wüsste, dass ich hier so faul liege, während er Appell hält.

sagen kann:

1. *Wüsste* ist Irrealis, der Sprecher geht davon aus, dass der Wachtmeister es nicht weiß.
2. Der Satz ist nicht als Wunsch formuliert, das wäre "Wenn der Wachtmeister **nur** wüsste...".
3. "... dass ich hier **so faul** liege ..." weist darauf hin, dass der Sprecher denkt, dass dem Wachtmeister das nicht gefallen würde. Das muss man, denke ich, im Zusammenhang mit dem Fiebertraum und mit Auffassungen von soldatischer Pflicht sehen, und man kann darüber spekulieren, wie es gemeint ist.

Mit der festen Formel "Wenn [Person] das wüsste!" ohne Hauptsatz möchte man im Allgemeinen sagen, dass in dem Fall etwas ganz anders wäre -- positiv oder negativ.

> "Wenn der Chef wüsste, dass du schon wieder Kaffepause machst!" *( ... gäbe es jetzt aber ein Donnerwetter!)*
> "Wenn ich das gewusst hätte!" *(... hätte ich ganz anders/besser gehandelt.)*
> ["Wenn das der Führer wüsste!"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wenn_das_der_F%C3%BChrer_w%C3%BCsste)